# Calling overloaded function on an object casted as Enum

Tags: c#, game-development

In our game we have different Enums defined to store the names of items of different types...
For example: OreName.Iron, OreName.Stone, OreName.Wood...
(same goes for other Enums like ToolName, ConsumableName...)

Now when it seems convenient, an item name Enum is sometimes stored as an (object) so that
we don't have one variable for each of the item names.

Problem is that when I wanna call a function on the item name that is stored in this object,
I first have to find out which Enum item name is actually in that object
(doing a lot of else-ifs where I try to cast the object as such and such),
and only then I call the overloaded function for that particular item name Enum.

This works just fine, but I thought I'd try to play around a bit with delegates and stuff to
figure out a more syntax efficient way of doing the same thing.

Didn't really figure out much - all I managed to do is create another overload for the concerned function
which takes an object as an argument, finds the item name Enum that is inside of that object and then
calls the appropriate overload on that item name... it reduces the code length in other scripts and is also
a bit easier to understand which is really all I'm looking for...

Now what I wanna achieve is writing a function that would somehow take an object and a overloaded function
as a parameter, figure out what item name is stored in the object and then call the overloaded function
on that item name... thing is I don't really know if it's possible... if it's a stupid idea I'm just
gonna stick with the way I'm doing it rn.

Comment: Would be helpful to see some code. What do you mean by _an item name Enum is sometimes stored as an (object)_?  What was the code for your previous solution? What is the code for your new solution? Unfortunately there is a lot of unknowns that can make your question hard to answer. It's possible, but without knowing your specifics we would likely just be guessing.

Comment: You could create a class `Ore`, which has a `string Name` and delegates such as `Action DoSomething` as properties. Then you could create static readonly instances such as `Iron`, `Stone`, etc. and use those in lieu of enums (and a private constructor to ensure that *only* those instances are available). I have successfully used this in a few use cases to implement "more powerful enums", I don't know if this design pattern is well-known or has a name.